# How to display picture in picture object using path in crystal report C#.net

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

```
public  class  studentlist
        {
          public string Photopath1 { get; set; }   
        }
var query = (from b in db.User_Students_Registration select new { b.Photopath});
 if (query.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var a in query)
                {
                Pictureobject p=(Pictureobject)cr.ReportDefinition.Sections                                                                              ["Section3"]ReportObjects["rptStudentDetailstext1"];
                 p.Picture =  a.Photopath;
                  }
             }
```

//This code is for displaying image from Database Using path in Crystal Report.
//But My image does not display in Picture object. Please Help Me